# Use object to cut through other object in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, layers

Basically, this white bit is being used to split the lines. I want the image to be entirely transparent, and in order to do so I want the white to be where the black objects are "cut", so I can delete the white or make it transparent.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selecting both objects, Object -> Clip -> Set Inverse fixed it

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Don't forget to choose your own answer as best if this solved your problem.